# Extending jQuery, loop through all selected elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery function to make all elements the same height.

I want to call it like this

```
$('ul#items li').MakeSameHeight();
```

That should make all li's the same height. So I need to loop through all the li's and get the max height. How do I do that? eg.

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MakeSameHeight() = function (opts) {
    // What do I put here?
  };
} (jQuery));
```

**EDIT :**

If anyone is curious, here is my final function, thanks to PSL

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MakeSameHeight = function (opts) {
    var maxH = 0;
    this.each(function () {
      maxH = Math.max(maxH, $(this).height());
    });
    this.each(function () {
      $(this).height(maxH);
    });
    return this;
  };
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: We don't write code for you at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:-

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MakeSameHeight = function (opts) {

//this inside the jquery plugin function refers to the result of jquery selector which          
 //itself is a jquery object. In this case it is list of li's
      this.each(function(){ //iterate through the selected elements
         alert($(this).css('height'));  //here do $(this) to get that particular element
         //to set the height $(this).css('height','yourheightvalue');
      });
    // What do I put here?

   return this;  //return the elements back for chaining.
  };
} (jQuery));

$('ul#items li').MakeSameHeight();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w74WG/)

Example:-

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.MakeSameHeight = function (opts) {
      this.each(function(){
     $(this).css('height', opts.height);
      });
    return this;
  };
} (jQuery));

$('ul#items li').MakeSameHeight({'height':'30px'});
```

Comment: Great, glad to know this is what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.each($('ul#items li'), function() {
// or: $('ul#items li').each(function() {
        $(this).css('height','someHeight');
    });
});
```

Comment: why not `$('ul#items li').each`?